Power Analysis for Interaction in Linear Mixed Model
I am trying to run a power analysis for an interaction in a linear mixed model to figure out the necessary sample size.
The model has the following structure:
Y ~ C * X + (1|Subject)
Y and X are continuous variables, while C is a two level factor (sum contrast coded) and within subject.
I know the expected effect size of the main effect between X and Y which is around beta =  0.27. Now I would like to find out the sample size for different interaction effect sizes (so basically run a sensitivity analysis).
I am aware of the discussion that interaction effect sizes often necessitate larger sample sizes (https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2018/03/15/need16/). However, these estimations seem to consider only between subject studies.
I also tried to use the InteractionPoweR package but I am not sure that it is applicable to my case.
I would be grateful for any help!

Do any of the packages in the "Power analysis and simulation" section of the mixed models task view do what you need?

Sometimes a quick peek into the mixed models documentation can be helpful (Thanks to the comment by Ben Bolker). The package "mixedpower" essentially does what I need: https://github.com/DejanDraschkow/mixedpower. It allows you to set the smallest effect sizes of interest, vary coefficients (main effects, interactions), and simulate different sample sizes.
